# jquery window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, window

i have this script below that will resize the ".content" on window resize it works fine but the only problem is that it jerks it waits until the resize has finished and then resizes the ".content" is there a wait to smooth the resizing that it resizes while the window resizes?

javascript

```
function foo(){
    //e.cancelBubble = true; 
    $('.content').each(function (){
        p = $('.content').parent();
        var ch = 0;
        var cw = 0
        c = p.children().each(function (i,n){
            ch +=$(this).height()
            cw +=$(this).width()
        });
        $(this).height(p.height()-(ch-$(this).height()) )
            .width(p.width()-(cw-$(this).width()) )
        t = $('#tmp');
        t.text('p:height: ' +p.height()+' c:'+ch );
    });
}
$(window).resize(foo)
```

css

```
        html,body{height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        .holder{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: yellow;
        }
        .header{ 
            background-color: red;
        }
        .footer{ 
            background-color: brown;
        }
        .content{
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }
```

html

```
<body onload="foo();" onresize="foo()">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="header">
            #header
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            #content
            <div id="tmp">Waiting...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            #footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [jquery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

http://ajaxmint.com/2009/11/jquery-animation-easing-plugin-example/

This smooths the animations.

Comment: If you want to use animations, remember to use `stop()` before triggering the animation so that you don't end up with thousands of stacked animations running at once.